# Split Javascript String

Tags: javascript, split, var

I've got a javascript string called cookie and it looks like that:

```
__utma=43024181.320516738.1346827407.1349695412.1349761990.10; __utmz=43024181.1346827407.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utmb=43024181.19.10.1349761990; __utmc=43024181; language=en
```

It could have more ;xxxxxx; but always the entries will be surrounded by ;.
Now i want to split my var into a array and search for the entry "language=xy", this entry should be saved in "newCookie".

Could anyone help me please i'm completly stucked at splitting the var into a array and search for the entry.

Thanks for helping and sharing

Comment: @user1109719 Java !== JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var cookie = '__utma=43024181.320516738.1346827407.1349695412.1349761990.10; __utmz=43024181.1346827407.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utmb=43024181.19.10.1349761990; __utmc=43024181; language=en;';

var cookie_array = cookie.split(';'); // Create an Array of all cookie values.

// cookie_array[0] = '__utma=43024181.320516738.1346827407.1349695412.1349761990.10'
// cookie_array[1] = '__utmz=43024181.1346827407.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)'
// cookie_array[2] = '__utmb=43024181.19.10.1349761990'
// cookie_array[3] = '__utmc=43024181'
// cookie_array[4] = 'language=en'

var size = cookie_array.length; // Get Array size to prevent doing lookups in a loop.

for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    var keyval = cookie_array[i].split('='); // Split into a key value array

    // What we're trying to find now.
    // keyval[0] = 'language'
    // keyval[1] = 'en'

    if (keyval[0] == 'language') { //keyval[0] is left of the '='
        //write new cookie value here
        console.log('Language is set to ' + keyval[1]);  // keyval[1] is right side of '='
    }
}
```

Hope this helps ya out.

For more info on the `split()` method look at [`split()` Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: Should be `; i < size` and not `; i<= size`

Comment: Thanks @Brombomb but last question is is var cookie now == language=en ? Or could you tell me how to set it ;)? Would be very nice i'm a completly javascript noob.

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple regexp for this:

```
var getLanguage = function(cookie){
    var re = new RegExp(/language=([a-zA-Z]+);/);
    var m = re.exec(cookie);
    return m?m[1]:null;
};

var lang = getLanguage('__utma=43024181.320516738.1346827407.1349695412.1349761990.10; __utmz=43024181.1346827407.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utmb=43024181.19.10.1349761990; __utmc=43024181; language=en;'); 
// lang = "en"
```